# How to load thousands of markers in Google Maps without performance problems and delays

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map made of 4627 markers exported from a MySQL database. I use the MarkerClusterer library to group the markers, however I notice that there is a significant delay and maybe a web browser crash in the future. How can improve it, how can I show them very fast without implications? Do I have to use MarkerManager or MarkerOverlay.

Code:

```
var markerCluster;
var gmarkers = []; 
var markerclusterer = null;
var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(37.929162, 23.6994703); //Google map Coordinates
var map;
var infowindow1;
infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var infowindow3;
var edit_address;
var pillar_rel;
var check;

map_initialize(); // initialize google map

//############### Google Map Initialize ##############
function map_initialize()
{
    var googleMapOptions = 
    { 
        center: mapCenter, // map center
        zoom: 15, //zoom level, 0 = earth view to higher value
        maxZoom: 35,
        minZoom: 3,
        zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL //zoom control size
        },
        scaleControl: true, // enable scale control
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // google map type
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_map"), googleMapOptions); 

    //Load Markers from the XML File, Check (map_process.php)
    $.get("map_process.php", function (data) {
        $(data).find("marker").each(function () 
        {
            var point   = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat($(this).attr('lat')),parseFloat($(this).attr('lng')));
            var township = ("Περιοχή : ").concat($(this).attr('township'));
            var fop = ("Κατηγορία : ").concat($(this).attr('fop'));
            var name = ("Ιστός : ").concat($(this).attr('name'));

            create_marker(point, township, fop, name, address, type, fot, lamp, power, vlaves, pillar, pillar_relation, username, false, false, false, "icons/pillar-small-red.png");               
        });
        markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers,
        {
            imagePath: 'icons/m/m'
        });
    });
}
//############### Create Marker Function ##############
function create_marker(MapPos, MapTitle, MapDesc, Yliko, Ypsos, Plithos, TyposFot, TyposLamp, Power, Vlaves, Pillar, Pillar_Relation, User, InfoOpenDefault, DragAble, Removable, iconPath)
{
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: MapPos,
        map: map,
        draggable:DragAble,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title:"ΚΟΛΟΝΑ ΔΕΗ",
        icon: iconPath
    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
}
```

I am fetching the markers from an XML file generated from a .php file.

Comment: I managed to find the solution. Just use JSON instead of XML! JSON is much faster compared to XML.